# How do I share mouse events between multiple canvases?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, dom-events

Say I have below

```
const canvas1 = document.createElement("canvas");
const canvas2 = document.createElement("canvas");
canvas1.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas2.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas1.height = window.innerHeight;
canvas1.height = window.innerHeight;
canvas1.addEventListener('click', onClickCanvas1);
canvas2.addEventListener('click', onClickCanvas2);
```

Because both canvases are located exactly the same location, the click event can only be listened to canvas1 or canvas2 (either canvas with more z-index value).

Is there any way to get both canvases to listen to the same mouse event?

Comment: I cannot see why you would do that. That's a clear [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)

Comment: Thank you for your swift reply.

The thing is "canvas1" is actually from a third party library which I do not have much control over. This canvas provides background contents but I need to draw another contents using pixijs on top of this background. Unfortunately, the webgl context for canvas1 cannnot be shared with canvas2 so having two differernt canvases was my only option.

Answer (score 2):

Since your canvases are overlapping with a higher z-index, simply assign the "click" to a common parent element

```
someElementWrapper.addEventListener("click", (ev) => {
  const bcr = ev.currentTarget.getBoundingClientRect();
  const x = ev.clientX - bcr.left; 
  const y = ev.clientY - bcr.top;
  // here pass the x and y coordinates in your app logic. For example:
  updateAllCanvases(x, y);
});
```

Alternatively, add CSS `pointer-events: none;` to your own canvas.

```html
<div id="wrapper"> <!-- I LISTEN TO MOUSE/TOUCH EVENTS! YEY -->
  <canvas id="canvas-others"></canvas> <!-- HAS ITS OWN EVENTS -->
  <canvas id="canvas-mine"></canvas>  <!-- HAS POINTER-EVENTS: NONE -->
</div>
```

Or simply - assign events directly to the 3rd party canvas.

Comment: Thank you for your solution. 

Do you think this is the only option? "canvas1" is actually from a third party library which has already been configured to have multiple event listeners. Therefore, I would like to simply get canvas2 to listen to the mouse events on canvas1 if possible..

Comment: @rks if your canvas2 does not have any necessary mouse events, you could simply use CSS `#canvas2 {pointer-events: none; }` and all your mouse events will pass through to the canvas below

Comment: C.Bujian

Yeah, currently I have "pixiDiv.style.pointerEvents = "none";" 
But unfortunately,  the Graphic objects inside pixiDiv also needs to have "hitArea" and listen to "click" and "drag" events..

Comment: @rks as I said, add pointer-events: none; to your canvas and listen for mouse/touch Events from your parent wrapper element. Not from canvas.

Comment: Why use event.currentTarget to get the BBox? You want the BBox of the canvas not of the wrapper.